# JavaScript Custom Alert Box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd Like to make a custom `alert` box, usually an `alert` box would have OK, but i want to add more buttons like 'yes', 'no' or 'hit that guy', right now I only know how to make `alert`boxes, `confirm`boxes and `prompt`boxes. 
 I want it to look like on chrome when the page is not responding you can choose to wait or kill the pages.  [Here](http://www.google.ie/search?q=chrome%20not%20responding%20box&biw=1680&bih=925&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=HkbSVNuHGIjg7QaRnIGoBw&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#tbm=isch&q=chrome%20page%20unresponsive%20box&imgdii=_) is a picture of what I am trying to do. I only want to use JavaScript or jQuery, and no other languages please.
Thanks for helping.
P.S. Sorry for the wall of text and not much code.

Comment: http://ninodezign.com/free-awesome-jquery-plugin-for-custom-alert-box/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can define your own dialogs like this:

```
$("<div>Test message</div>").dialog();
```

If no, you can define your own function to use.

```
custom_alert();
custom_alert("Display Message");
custom_alert("Display Message", "Set Title");

function custom_alert(output_msg, title_msg)
{
    if (!title_msg)
        title_msg = 'Alert';

    if (!output_msg)
        output_msg = 'No Message to Display.';

    $("<div></div>").html(output_msg).dialog({
        title: title_msg,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function() 
            {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: That is if the OP is using jQuery UI...

Comment: @epascarello seems he was using it at all... ;)

Answer (score 0):

The system `alert` dialog is as-is. You can't change it. You seem to know that you can use a custom dialog message, but don't want to because they don't look nice? You know you can customize the look, or use a pre-defined style. Take a look at jQuery UI "themeroller" for additional styles:

http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/